# Ookla Speed Tests on VMWare ESXI Ubuntu

Tags: vmware-esxi

I just wanted to ask if there's any recommendation for performing Ookla speed tests from a Ubuntu ESXI Virtual Machine. We're getting 900 Mbps Download/ 900 Mbps Upload from a normal laptop using ubuntu, but when we use an Ubuntu ESXI Virtual Machine we're getting a much lower upload ~500 Mbps.

Comment: Well, there's a ton of info on performance tuning of network on ESXi out there. What have you attempted? How is things configured?

Comment: Well, the VMWare ESXi is connected to a cisco switch, which is then connected to the Cable Modem (Internet connection). 
When testing by using a laptop, I plug-in the laptop straight to the Cable Modem (Internet connection).

Comment: How is things configured? What NIC's is in use? What virtual NIC's? VLAN's? Where is things tagged? How's routing handled?

Comment: NIC -QLogic 577xx/578xx 10 Gb Ethernet BCM57810 
vNIC - VMXNET3
VLAN - Access VLAN on Cisco
Tagging - 802.1Q on uplinks
Routing - no routing straight L2